# Segment to filter through categories slug

Tags: categories, segments

I've seen plenty examples of using the uri segment like below, but it ain't working for me, anyone had same sort of issue?

```
{% set segment = craft.request.segment(2) %}
{% set pageCats = craft.categories('photoCategories').slug('segment') %}
{% set entries = craft.assets.group('photoUpload').relatedTo(pageCats).find() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.stuff }}
{% endfor %}
```

It works if I hard code the segment name `.slug('skateboards')` and the segment does render when `{{ segment }}` on other areas of the same page.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the ' ' from segment in line 2

e.g.

```
{% set pageCats = craft.categories('photoCategories').slug(segment) %}
```

Comment: yes, that worked, and i was sure i'd checked that too!